Python aiogram exe bot can't send photo
I have this code to send an image
@router.message(CommandStart()) async def cmd_help(message: Message,state : FSMContext): await state.clear() file_path = "app/other/image.jpg" await message.reply_photo( photo = FSInputFile( path=file_path ) )
and it works if run with python main.py, but when I try to compile and open it with
            pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/tgbot/app/other/*;. " -F -i "path:)\icon.ico" main.py
error appears
`
TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientOSError: [Errno 2] Can not write request                    body for https://api.telegram.org/ bottoken:)/sendPhoto
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 637, in write_bytes
File "aiohttp\multipart.py", line 993, in write
File "aiohttp\payload.py", line 442, in write
File "aiogram\types\input_file.py", line 103, in read
File "aiofiles\base.py", line 98, in aenter
File "aiofiles\threadpool_init_.py", line 94, in _open
File "concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'app/other/image.jpg'
        The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

            Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "aiogram\client\session\aiohttp.py", line 181, in make_request
        File "aiohttp\client.py", line 1353, in __aenter__
    File "aiohttp\client.py", line 684, in _request
       File "aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 999, in start
    File "aiohttp\streams.py", line 640, in read
      aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientOSError: [Errno 2] Can not write request body for bottoken:)                /sendPhoto

         During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
           File "aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
        File "aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
       File "aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 56, in __call__
         File "aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    File "aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
            File "aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
        File "aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
        File "aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 146, in propagate_event
       File "aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 141, in _wrapped
      File "aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 174, in _propagate_event
        File "aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 146, in propagate_event
 File "aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 141, in _wrapped
   File "aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 166, in _propagate_event
       File "aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
        File "aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
      File "app\handlers.py", line 35, in cmd_help
          File "aiogram\methods\base.py", line 84, in emit
       File "aiogram\client\bot.py", line 488, in __call__
        File "aiogram\client\session\base.py", line 254, in __call__
        File "aiogram\client\session\aiohttp.py", line 188, in make_request
     aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientOSError: [Errno 2] Can       not write request body for https://api.telegram.org/bottoken:) /sendPhoto

`
I tried to specify the path differently and change the data in --add-data
